# Firebase Android - create node from keys in an Arraylist

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `ArrayList` full of specific keys. How would I go about making a new node with just the keys in the Arraylist?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, new to asking questions on here. It was answered for me though so thanks Stack overflow community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ArrayList` that look like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To create a new node using only the keys, please use the folliwing code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
for(String s : list) {
    rootRef.child("yourNode").child(s).setValue(true);
}
```

And your database structure will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- yourNode
          |
          --- arraListKey1: true
          |
          --- arraListKey2: true
          |
          --- //and so on
```

Comment: You're welcome @MarcoGonzalez ! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more? What have you managed to do so far? If for example i have an arraylist of strings containing two items, item1 and item2, then i can loop through the arraylist and pushing the string to your firebase server as the key. For example

```
ArrayList<String> myArray= new ArrayList<>();
myArray.add(item1);
myArray.add(item2);


for (int i =0; i<myArray.size();i++){
    String key = myArray.get(i) ;

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.child(key);
    ref.child(key).child("itemUnderThisKey").setValue("value you want to set")


}
```

This is how ur firebase structure will look like :

[image]

Best thing is to understand the firebase data structures and you can make them suite your whatever needs. Hope the above will help.